# Wrong class types used in sql when STI used with join query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2, sti

I've recently upgraded from Rails 4.1.4 to 4.2.8 and I got very strange behavior. 
So we have table 
`class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base` and tables `Doctor, Assistant, Substitute` that are inherited from it.

So when I'm outside of any of those classes and do call (rails console, specs)

`Doctor.all.to_sql` => 
`"SELECT \"identities\".* FROM \"identities\" WHERE \"identities\".\"type\" IN ('Doctor')"` which is good.

When I do same call but from class method in Assistant model, it produces following
`Doctor.all.to_sql` => 

`"SELECT \"identities\".* FROM \"identities\" WHERE \"identities\".\"type\" IN ('Assistant', 'Substitute')"` which is wrong.

While i'm inside class method in Assistant model and do

`Doctor.unscoped.all` => `"SELECT \"identities\".* FROM \"identities\" WHERE \"identities\".\"type\" IN ('Doctor')"` good query.

I've checked if we set default_scope somewhere but we don't. Also, it's quite tricky as when I do 
`SomeTable.joins(:identities)` I can't unscope `identities` which leads me to wrong query.

So, I'm not quite sure what's happened after upgrading, but I know it does works with old Rails 4.1.4.

Any hint would be helpful.

Regads

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "When I'm inside, for example Assistant"? The call to `Doctor.all.to_sql` should always result in the same SQL, because you are just calling a method on the `Doctor` model.

Comment: exactly and that's not what is happening. Let's say we have class method on Assistant model, and when I call `Doctor.all.to_sql` or `Identity.all.to_sql` inside that method, it gives me sql query with types (Assistant, Substitute). When I use rails console for example, or in specs and do the same query it suppose to be fine.

Comment: Could be some kind of Rails bug... have you tried upgrading to 4.2.x? I think 4.1.4. is a rather old version.

Comment: No rails 4.1.4 works as expected but 4.2.8 does those messy things :/

Comment: Maybe check the release notes? I still don't get how the behavior could be dependent on the context... independent of where any method on Doctor is being called, the result should be the same. I totally believe you that it is not... but for me that would be a red flag, maybe try a newer version? I think there's also 4.2.11?

Comment: Yes I agree with you it is totally weird. I will see if I can reproduce some more things and to upgrade to 4.2.11 to see what would be behavior there. Then I will see should I write to them or not :) 
Thanks for you support anyway

Comment: @bo-oz I just upgraded to 4.2.11 and seems it works fine. I'm checking now this whole thing one more time before I write to rails. Thanks for suggestion again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to Rails 4.2.11, issue has gone. 
I will put some more effort to reproduce this behavior on older versions and to report to rails team if necessary.